# RegExp returning empty string

Tags: php, regex

So, this feels silly, but I can't get my head around it.

I'm trying to catch a id-code and name from a log file, the example boils down to this

```
$line = "exten => 3002,2,Dial(/dev/null,20); Name Here";
$match = "/exten => ([0-9]{4}),2,Dial\(\/dev\/null,20\); ([\w]*)/Us";

if (preg_match($match, $line, $result))
{
    var_dump($result);  
}
```

Where I want to grab `3002` and `Name Here`. The output I get is this

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(36) "exten => 3002,2,Dial(/dev/null,20); "
  [1]=>
  string(4) "3002"
  [2]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

This feels *way* to silly to get stuck on, but I'm at a loss, so..I can haz help plz?

Comment: Besides the ungreedines, you also look for just letters. But `Name Here` also contains a space. So `[\w\s]*` might be in order.

Comment: @mario you (and the others) are correct, I missed the fact that `\w` does not match spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought:

```
...([\w]*)/Us";
        ^  ^
        |  |
        |  \_ Ungreedy
        |
         \_ Zero or more
```

**Edit:**

If you just want the rest of the line:

```
$match = "/exten => ([0-9]{4}),2,Dial\(\/dev\/null,20\); (.+)$/Us";
                                                         ^^^^^
```

Comment: Removeing `U` gives me "Name", so that's closer (also changed `*` to `+`)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is surely  : ([\w]*) at the end.

\w won't match whitespace , and "Name Here" has whitespaces.

i would recommend ([\w\s]*) for matching "Name Here"

Comment: `\s` will match newline, I'm not sure that's desirable, although I guess we don't know enough about this to be sure.

Comment: In this case the string will be terminated with a newline, and I would prefer not to catch it. Though if I did it would be easily trimmed.